# Analytic maps via Baire category method

Tags: real-analytic-structures

The Baire category method is sometimes useful in constructing smooth maps between manifolds with prescribed properties. I would like to know whether there are any (non-trivial) situations in which the method helps (not necessarily as the main tool) in some real-analytic constructions.

Comment: Does the set of real-analytic maps $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ have a natural topology?  Is it Polish?

Comment: I am afraid it does not, at least not that I know of. There is the following vague idea that I had in mind when asking the question. Let us assume that we found some way of assigning to each object of some family an analytic map. Maybe we could then apply the Baire method to our family, appropriately topologized, and obtain a map as we wanted. An elementary example could be the Lie algebra of a Lie group. It is complete in the norm topology and each element can be identified with an (analytic) one-parameter subgroup.

Comment: The space of real analytic functions has a natural locally convex topology whose rather delicate properties have been investigated in considerable detail over the years.  You could start by checking out A. Martineau, D. Vogt and P. Domański with a search machine.